# Arabic turn to strange Question marks

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, character

After typing in Arabic in the form I press an insert button to insert the fields in the db. But characters turn to strange question marks like :`"?????"`. That doesn't happen with numbers or English characters.

How to type Arabic and still have it in the db as Arabic, not as `"?????"`?

[image]

Here is some code

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StoreConnectionString"].ToString());

        public AddBook()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string X;
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StoreItem", cn);
                Int32 count = (Int32)cm.ExecuteScalar();
                X = count.ToString();
                cn.Close();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into StoreItem (ID, Title, Writer, Price, Qun, Date) Values ('" + X + "','" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy") + "')", cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

                textBox1.Text = null;
                textBox2.Text = null;
                textBox3.Text = null;
                textBox4.Text = null;

                this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

And

```
private void Rsh()
{
    SqlDataAdapter ADAP = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM StoreItem", cn);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    ADAP.Fill(DS, "Store");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables["Store"];
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "#";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "عنوان الكتاب";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "الكاتب";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "السعر";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "الكمية";
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "تاريخ دخول";
}
```

Comment: Hint: What character encoding are you using

Comment: how to know witch character encoding im using?

Comment: For a start, if your column is of varchar type, alter it to nvarchar.

Comment: Show some code. Are you using parameterised queries? Whata re the datatype of the parameters? What is the datatype and collation of the column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

surly Your datatype for those column is varchar.

You just need to change it to nvarchar and it will be get saved. Also dont forget to add a prefix N. Refer to following query.

if name is nvarchar

```
insert into Emp (name) values (N'test')
```

Comment: Wow THis 'N' saved my project, thanQ ya Shaikh

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screen shot it looks as though you already have some unicode data but as I rough top-down walk through. You should be using `nvarchar` to store your strings as it is unicode it will record Arabic or extended characters without issue.

You also need to check that your character encoding is setup (UTF8 is usually a good bet) and passed through all various places correctly. If you are using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` then it would be best to pass the value as a parameter to ensure that everything is being handled correctly and avoid injection attacks. If you are using Entity Framework there should be no additional steps to my knowledge.

Comment: good point on nvarchar , but how to know my character encoding and change it to UTF8?

Comment: Show some code and tell us what you are using (as in my question). Are you using `SqlCommand`, Entity Framwork? Show us the code where you actually try to save the value back to the database. That will give us a better idea.